# Show One to Many in One Row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'd like to reformat a cross reference table I am using before merging it to my data.

Certain parts have a one to many relationship and I want to reformat these cases into a single row so I capturing all the info when I later merge/vlookup this table to my data.  Most of the data is a one to one relationship so the solution has to be selective.

Currently:

```
    Marketing Number    SKU
0                XXX    111
1                XXX    222
2                XXX    333
```

What I want:

```
   Marketing Number               SKU
0               XXX     111; 222; 333
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `groupby` to get the `SKU` values into a `list`
- Then join the list values.

  - Since the values in the list are `int` type, they must be converted to strings, to join them.

```py
import pandas as pd

# data and dataframe
data = {'Marketing Number': ['XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'y', 'z', 'a'],
        'SKU': [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

  Marketing Number  SKU
0              XXX  111
1              XXX  222
2              XXX  333
3                y  444
4                z  555
5                a  666

# groupby with agg list
dfg = df.groupby('Marketing Number', as_index=False).agg({'SKU': list})

# join into string
dfg.SKU = dfg.SKU.apply(lambda x: '; '.join([str(i) for i in x]))

  Marketing Number            SKU
0              XXX  111; 222; 333
1                a            666
2                y            444
3                z            555
```